# logical test if string is exactly 2 or more spaces

Tags: regex, r

I want to be able to test a string if it is:

1. comprised of 2 or more characters
2. and all characters are spaces

So let us say we have:

```
x <- c("   ", "   p", "\\s\\s", "\\s", " ", "d", "  ", "          ", ": ")
```

I would expect toe results to be:

```
TRUE FALSE TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE TRUE FALSE
```

I started by using something along the lines of:

```
log_test <- gregexpr(":", gsub("\\s", ":", x))
```

But then realized this was becoming convoluted, (subbing out spaces) leading to error prone responses.  For instance, if I continued down this road, the last element would wind up being `TRUE` even though it it has only one space because it contains a colon already.

*Please note that R has specific regex rules, to answer this correctly most likely requires knowledge of the R language.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another option:

```
grepl('^( |\\\\s){2,}$', x)
#[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

Answer (score 2):

Give this a try?

```
> x2 <- gsub('\\\\s',' ',x)
> grepl('[[:blank:]]{2,}',x2) & !grepl('[[:alnum:][:punct:]]',x2)
[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

You can also use `[:graph:]` to capture characters and punctuation:

```
> x2 <- gsub('\\\\s',' ',x)
> grepl('[[:blank:]]{2,}',x2) & !grepl('[[:graph:]]',x2)
[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

Comment: Works well, I'll hold off marking as correct for a bit and see if additional answers come in. +1